# Can I still use a GUI on a headless laptop (used for storage)?

Tags: laptop, headless, remote-management

My current laptop is falling apart, specifically the screen hinges. Once (or ideally before) they break, I'd like to run the machine as a storage device. I strongly prefer using GUIs over CLI.

Any recommendations on a distro/useful tools to install before turning it into a box? Any cautionary tales about running a laptop without a screen?

So far I imagine installing Ubuntu (not Server) and running Remmina to remoting in via VNC/etc.

Comment: No cautionary tales... but I can imagine your biggest problem would be from heat, laptops suffer from heat problems naturally and aren't really designed to run 24/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using it as a storage device I would configure it now, turn it on, and share your drive via NFS/SAMBA, etc, then never touch it again.

Effecively, you're turning your laptop into a NAS. Something like [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org) might be worth looking at. [It provides a web-based GUI](http://www.freenas.org/about/features/#webinterface) which should suffice for most tasks, leaving remote/command line work for only very deep stuff (which is typical on any system, and FreeNAS is well-documented and has an active community were you could seek further support).

What I would question is now often you really will need to remote into it. You're just sharing storage, so why connect to the box?

Answer (score 4):

You could also use X forwarding over ssh to run the occasional GUI tool (you don't need an X-server on the "storage device" then to run GUI apps).

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative to VNC is [NX](http://www.nomachine.com/), but it's a bit harder to setup.